# Oracle .Net Core Managed Driver : Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.TimeStamp..cctor() exception

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-core, ado.net, odp.net

We have started using  Beta release .Net Core Managed driver released by Oracle http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html. 
It works fine except when we use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility nuget package in our .net core application for accessing Active Directory. The db.open() command just doesn't work and throws exception "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.TimeStamp..cctor() exception". Let me know if anybody has tried the beta version with windows compatibility pack or has solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to get it work by removing the windows compatibility nuget package from the solution and manually adding reference to System.DirectoryServices DLL from windows compatibility package to the solution.

Windows compatibility nuget package has some more DLLs apart from System.DirectoryServices DLL and one of them is causing this problem. Because I needed only the ldap feature so I removed all other DLLs and references only the DirectoryServices DLL and that worked.